# How to use sockets by flask_socketio with existing non-socket Flask app with REST-API?

Tags: python, sockets, rest, flask, socket.io

I have a large Flask application. It works by using Flask-RESTful. I need to add a small portion of the support sockets without changing their familiar environment for the rest of the code. When I wrap my app as in example and start it as

```
socketio = SocketIO(app) 
socketio.run(app)
```

, then it stop working regular part of the rest-and development-server does not even start.

How to solve this problem? I need only a small part of the application with sockets. But socketio whole application takes over, which is why it stops working.

Comment: post your code! I use FLask-SocketIO and RESTfull at the same time with no problems

Comment: @CESCO I have a similar issue and need urgent help. can you help me out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735195/to-implement-a-web-socket-feature-with-flask-restful-rest-api-on-the-server-si)? sorry for breaking the rules